# Pandas Read CSV file with characters in front of data table

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some problems with reading CSV file into DataFrame. My CSV file is machine-stored file with several lines of file and data info in front of data table, as shown below:

```
! Software: xyz
! Testplan: C:\Software\abc
! Probe Plan: abc
! Software: xyz
! Datafile: C:\Software\data.CSV
! Description: data
Name, Location, Price, Quantity, 
Jack, New York, 39, 20,
Tom, Los Angeles, 35, 18,
Carl, San Jose, 48, 22,
Jean, Dallas, 59, 11,
```

I would like to skip the characters and only read the data table into DataFrame. In addition, read the column names as the head of DataFrame.

So the desired DataFrame is like below:

Column Head: Name    Location      Price   Quantity 
             Jack    New York        39      20 
             Tom     Los Angeles     35      18 
             Carl    San Jose        48      22 
             Jean    Dallas          59      11

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just skip the rows using the `skiprows` argument of `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows=6)

   Name      Location   Price   Quantity    
0  Jack      New York      39         20 NaN
1   Tom   Los Angeles      35         18 NaN
2  Carl      San Jose      48         22 NaN
3  Jean        Dallas      59         11 NaN
```

Comment: or `comment ='!'`